# Storing current cell value, adding formula then changing format to custom

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to have the current value of a cell stored in a variable, its new value changed to a formula, then formatting the cell with a custom type of the stored variable.

For example:
Cell B3 says "Hello"
"Hello" is stored in variable sValue
Cell B3 gets changed to equal D3 (=D3)
Custom Format Type is completed to still read "Hello"

However, I get a

> Run-time error '13':

> Type mismatch

On sValue.

Updated code based on Comments:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim sValue As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B41")) Is Nothing Then
    sValue = Target.Value
    Target.Formula = "=D" & Target.Row
    Target.NumberFormat = Chr(34) & sValue & Chr(34)
End If
End Sub
```

The reason for the offset is because when I hit **ENTER** it performs the script on the new cell, when I am intending it to be on the above row that I edited. Not sure how to get it to run on the current cell without changing the cell.

Comment: when you manually change a cell, `Target` will be the cell that just changed and not the cell into which you just entered.

Comment: That's good to know, so essentially change ActiveCell.Value to Target.Value and Target.Formula.

Comment: correct, use `Target` in place of all `ActiveCell` and remove the `Offset`

Comment: You will also need to escape `\ ` any letter that is used as format short hand.  For example  `H` is hour and will be read as such.  So you will need to do a replace for every one that could be used, which is quite a few.

Comment: it should be `Target.NumberFormat = `

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I understand what you're saying about shorthand interference but where does that interfere in my case? Also still getting a error on my variable.

Comment: see my last comment for the error.  for example `Hello` will come out as `{somenumber}ello` With `{somenumber}` being a number between 0 and 23.

Comment: I updated the post with the new details. So I can't just store the cell value as a variable string?

Comment: You updated the code but not the issue.  As the error is probably different now.

Comment: Does it help that my variable will always be text? I think I was using Long incorrectly.

Comment: Yes it should be string, but it will still not format correctly.  It will fix the error.

Comment: So I changed it to String and get Run-time error '28': Out of stack space.

Comment: Now you need to disable the events and reenable after doing the changes.

Comment: BTW: I was wrong on needing the escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the comments:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sValue As String
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B41")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        On Error GoTo safeout
        sValue = Target.Value
        Target.Formula = "=D" & Target.Row
        Target.NumberFormat = Chr(34) & sValue & Chr(34)
    End If
safeout:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```